# User not able to sign out in firebase Flutter application

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

D/FirebaseAuth( 7994): Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
D/FirebaseAuth( 7994): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.

```
class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LandingPageState createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
  User _user;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _updateUser(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser);
  }
  void _updateUser(User user) {
    setState(() {
      _user = user;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_user == null) {
      return SignInPage(
        onSignIn: _updateUser,
      );
    }
    return HomePage(
      onSignOut: () => _updateUser(null),
    );
  }
}
```

Home page Code:-

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  HomePage({@required this.onSignOut});
  final VoidCallback onSignOut;
  Future<void> _signOut() async {

    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString()) ;
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Page'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              'Logout',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: _signOut,

          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my code but the user is not able to log out of my application.Can somebody tell me what to fix

Answer (score 1):

Try to await the `signout` call:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  HomePage({@required this.onSignOut});
  final VoidCallback onSignOut;
  Future<void> _signOut() async {    
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString()) ;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Page'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              'Logout',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () async => await _signOut(), // Updated code    
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this earlier but the same message is popping up